# Split a String on | (pipe) in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have the following text: `ARIYALUR:ARIYALUR|CHENNAI:CHENNAI|COIMBATORE:COIMBATORE|CUDDALORE:CUDDALORE|DINDIGUL:DINDIGUL|ERODE:ERODE|KANCHEEPURAM:KANCHEEPURAM|KANYAKUMARI:KANYAKUMARI|KRISHNAGIRI:KRISHNAGIRI|MADURAI:MADURAI|NAMAKKAL:NAMAKKAL|NILGIRIS:NILGIRIS|PERAMBALUR:PERAMBALUR|PONDICHERRY:PONDICHERRY|SALEM:SALEM|THANJAVUR:THANJAVUR|THENI:THENI|THIRUVALLUR:THIRUVALLUR|THOOTHUKUDI:THOOTHUKUDI|TIRUNELVELI:TIRUNELVELI|VELLORE:VELLORE|VILLUPURAM:VILLUPURAM|VIRUDHUNAGAR:VIRUDHUNAGAR|`

I tried to do a `split("|")` but my array is made up of single characters and not each district.

Comment: split takes a regex (regular expression), hence, as Haozhun says, it is a special character. There are others too, so be careful!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`|` is a special symbol in regular expression. Use `\\|` instead.

I'll explain why I appended 2 slashes. To escape the `|`, I need `\|`. However, to represent the string `\|`, `"\\|"` is required because `\` itself needs to be escaped in a string lateral.

And, as xagyg has pointed out in the comment, split will treat the parameter as a regular expression. It will not be treated as a plain string.

In this use case, you may be interested to learn about [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). You can do `Pattern.quote("|")`. This way, none of the characters will be treated as special ones.

Comment: @user903772 You need `"\\|"` because `\\` itself is a special symbol in String, therefore, you have to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the escape char before the meta char `|` which represnt `OR`. **Also since you need to pass the regex in split as String, you need to escape the escape character as well.**

Try below:

```
    String str = "ARIYALUR:ARIYALUR|CHENNAI:CHENNAI|COIMBATORE:COIMBATORE|CUDDALORE:CUDDALORE|DINDIGUL:DINDIGUL|ERODE:ERODE|KANCHEEPURAM:KANCHEEPURAM|KANYAKUMARI:KANYAKUMARI|KRISHNAGIRI:KRISHNAGIRI|MADURAI:MADURAI|NAMAKKAL:NAMAKKAL|NILGIRIS:NILGIRIS|PERAMBALUR:PERAMBALUR|PONDICHERRY:PONDICHERRY|SALEM:SALEM|THANJAVUR:THANJAVUR|THENI:THENI|THIRUVALLUR:THIRUVALLUR|THOOTHUKUDI:THOOTHUKUDI|TIRUNELVELI:TIRUNELVELI|VELLORE:VELLORE|VILLUPURAM:VILLUPURAM|VIRUDHUNAGAR:VIRUDHUNAGAR|";
    String [] tokens = str.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public static String[] splitWord(String x){
    String[] j = new String [200];
    for(int i=0;i<x.split("\|").length;i++){
        j[i] = x.split("\|")[i];
    }
    return j;
}
```

I came up with this method for these types of situations.
To use it, call the method and specify what word you need to access:

```
Classname.splitWord(String)[word in array];
```

Comment: That's terrible code, sorry. 1.) You're splitting the string each time you check the condition in the for loop and each time you copy the value. That's 2*n `split` calls where one would suffice. 2.) `200` as a magic number is a bad idea, what if `x` has 201 elements? 3.) Why do you *copy* the resulting array anyway? 4.) Why do you copy it manually instead of using something like `System.arraycopy` or simply `.clone()`.